# Checking multiple post parameters to see if they exist

Tags: php

So I'm trying to write a function in PHP which will essentially enumerate through a list of POST parameters I declare within the function arguments.

```
       case "send":
            if($this->checkPostParams(array('number', 'subject', 'amount', 'message')))
            {
                die("success");
            }
        break;
```

This part is where the function is called and I attempt to parse the array of POST parameters into the function's arguments.

```
private function checkPostParams($x)
{
    $status = 0;

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($x); $i++)
    {
        if(!isset($_POST[$i])) $status++;
    }

    return ($status == 0);
}
```

And here is the function that is being called where I enumerate through the POST parameters using **isset** to check if the parameters are existent or not, as soon as one parameter is not existent within the array I increment a variable outside of the for loop which will allow for the Boolean output and comparison at the end of the function.

It doesn't seem to be working at all and I'm not sure why.

Comment: It's not working is not a descriptive explanation at all as a programmer. What output do you currently get.

Comment: Welcome. "*It doesn't seem to be working at all*" will sadly not help anybody here. Please describe what doesn't work. Do you get any errors?

Comment: I get no output at all, completely null, no errors nothing

Comment: did you mean `$_POST[$x[$i]]`?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue, I just realised

Comment: I would assume the issue here is where you check $_POST[$i], $i is just a counter variable. might want to check $_POST[$x[$i]]. Or better yet. do a for ($i in x)... Then $i will be the variable instead of a counter.

Comment: `if(!isset($_POST[$x[$i]])) $status++;` worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Also, consider making Booleans when such needed. `$status = true;` and then set to `false` like: `if (!isset($_POST[$x[$I]])) $status = false;` and simply return `$status` in the end...

Comment: Why keep a counter? Just return `false` when your condition is met. And I would recommend `foreach`  instead of `for`.

Comment: I used for initially because it's more efficient than elegant

Comment: Good luck measuring the difference :-)

Comment: I do agree it may be a lot easier for me to realise how stupid I am using a foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function `checkPostParams()` you are passing an array containing number, subject etc...

```
   case "send":
        if($this->checkPostParams(array('number', 'subject', 'amount', 'message')))
        {
            die("success");
        }
    break;
```

`if(!isset($_POST[$i])) $status++;` this line will check index of `$i` in post that an integer value. You are getting all fields name in `$x` variable, so you have to check `$_POST[$x[$i]]`. Here `$x` has values like number, subject etc.. and `$i` is an integer. if you add index `$i` in `$x` you will get values and that value use in `$_POST`.

```
if(!isset($_POST[$x[$i]])) $status++;
```